# How to insert bulk message manually in AWS SQS queue from AWS UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to do some testing for my application where it is trying to fetch messages from SQS and trying to process in batches. So for that, i want to insert bulk message manually through sqs from aws UI. Can someone please help me on that.

I have gone through this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-getting-started.html but here they didn't tell how to insert suppose 1000 message at one go from sqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no bulk insert functionality in the UI. You would need to use a different tool for inserting those messages like the [AWS CLI tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/send-message-batch.html).

Note that the SQS API only allows inserting a batch of up to 10 messages at a time, so you'll have to write some code to do this in a loop.